# Securing local docker registry

Tags: security, docker, rhel7

We are maintaining our own local docker registry using `docker distribution services`

```
$ ps -ef | grep 1035
 root      1035     1  0 Apr04 ?        00:00:10 /usr/bin/registry serve /etc/docker-distribution/registry/config.yml
```

What are the ways to secure the local registry . Is it possible to implement the below

1) Authentication based download from local registry
2) SSL based docker pull 
Any other suggestions. We are using `Redhat 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation, you can use ssl certificate for your registry as the docker documentation here:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate

and for the authentication you can use Restricted access like this:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#restricting-access

for more control and a good UI I will recommmend using Portus

Answer (score 0):

We can Implement a Private docker registry with three different methods.

1. Create private docker registry with HTTP
2. Create private docker registry with SSL/TLS
3. Create a Private docker registry with SSL/TLS enabled and with basic authentication

each implementation has a slightly different configuration and it should be understood well. I have written a [blog post](https://geekdosage.com/how-to-create-a-private-docker-registry-in-ubuntu-20-04/) on this. You can read it for a better understanding.